# Preprocessing rules for modules in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoalumberjack

In [CocoaLumberjack issue #778](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/778), when `CocoaLumberjack` is linked as a dynamic framework, the line `#import "DDLogMacros.h"` in `CocoaLumberjack.h` doesn't have any effects. Therefore, `LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED`(which is defined in `DDLogMacros.h`) is undefined.

Can someone explain the mechanism about the preprocessing rules of Xcode modules?
It seems that the preprocessor doesn't "preprocess" the headers in modules.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about the preprocessing rules, but add
`#import <CocoaLumberJack/DDLog+LOGV.h>` can deal.

In the `CocoaLumberjack-umbrella.h`, the order like this:

```
#import "DDLog+LOGV.h"
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDLogMacros.h"
```

It's fine if i change the order like this:

```
#import "DDLogMacros.h"   
#import "DDLog+LOGV.h"
#import "DDLog.h"
```

In the `DDLog+LOGV.h` also define `LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED`, i guess that the order in `CocoaLumberjack-umbrella.h` will effect the macro